# How to enable apache2-mpm-worker on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to enable apache2-mpm-worker for apache2 - but no luck.
What is the procedure for installing and enabling apache2 mpm-working for ubuntu 13.10? Is there some hidden setting to convince different apache?

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 19 2014 20:56:01
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:23
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"

# uname -a
Linux Ubuntu-1310-saucy-64-minimal 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The apache says that still does not have worker.c

```
# /usr/sbin/apache2 -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c
```

The instalation went well

```
# sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom apache2-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/88.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 488 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
(Reading database ... 112810 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2 (from .../apache2_2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-mpm-worker.
Unpacking apache2-mpm-worker (from .../apache2-mpm-worker_2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for ufw ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2) ...
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                                        [ OK ] 
Setting up apache2-mpm-worker (2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2) ...
```

Comment: What is the output of `apache2 -V|grep MPM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apache2-mpm-worker package is just a transitional package that depends on the apache2 package. That package has the prefork, worker, itk, and event MPMs built as [dso modules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html#dynamic).

You can see them in all in mods-available

```
$ ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm*
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.conf  /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.load  /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.load
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_itk.conf    /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_worker.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_itk.load    /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_worker.load
```

and see the active on in mods-enabled

```
$ ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Mar 25 21:09 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_event.conf -> ../mods-available/mpm_event.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Mar 25 21:09 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_event.load -> ../mods-available/mpm_event.load
```

You can disable and enable modules with [*a2dismod* and *a2enmod*](http://man.he.net/man8/a2enmod).

You may want to stick with [event](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html) instead of [worker](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html).

Comment: This means there is no need to install apache2-mpm-worker ?

Comment: Correct; no need to install it.